# Unexpected Exception: name 'basestring' is not defined when invoking ansible2

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to execute ansible2 commands...

When I do:

```
ansible-playbook -vvv -i my/inventory my/playbook.yml
```

I get:

> Unexpected Exception: name 'basestring' is not defined
> the full traceback was:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> ```

```
  File "/usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook", line 85, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli.run())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ansible/cli/playbook.py", line 150, in run
    results = pbex.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ansible/executor/playbook_executor.py", line 87, in run
    self._tqm.load_callbacks()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_queue_manager.py", line 149, in load_callbacks
    elif isinstance(self._stdout_callback, basestring):
NameError: name 'basestring' is not defined
```

Here is `ansible --version`:

```
ansible 2.0.0.2
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

And here is `python --version`

```
Python 3.4.3
```

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Ansible below version 2.5 requires Python 2.6 or 2.7 on the control host: [Control Node Requirements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#control-node-requirements)

`basestring` is no longer available in Python 3. From [What’s New In Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit):

> The builtin `basestring` abstract type was removed. Use `str` instead. The `str` and `bytes` types don’t have functionality enough in common to warrant a shared base class. The `2to3` tool (see below) replaces every occurrence of `basestring` with `str`.

So the solution is to either upgrade Ansible or downgrade Python.

Comment: in case this helps anyone else, when i installed ansible using `pip` and `pip3`, it erroneously pointed to python3, but when i did `pip2 install ansible`, it worked fine, putting this at the top of each ansible utility: `#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7`

Comment: I feel like this is a flaw in pip or python packages or something. I shouldn't be able to pip3 install something that isn't compatible with python3.

Comment: I was able to get this working by installing ansible@2.5.0: `python3 -m pip install ansible==2.5.0`.

Comment: following the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#basestring), why not use `(str, bytes)` as `basestring`? For `isinstance(var, (str,bytes))` works perfectly.

Comment: So your suggestion is to rewrite the ansible code? Sure, go ahead...

Answer (score 25):

basestring is not available in Python 3.:

This can be fixed for python 2.x and 3.x with the following:

```
try:
  basestring
except NameError:
  basestring = str
```

Comment: Not that `isinstance(b"", basestring) == True` on Python 2 but `isinstance(b"", str) == False` on Python 3.

Comment: I like more this one since i need  the code to run in both environments. I find it hacky but is the fit for me now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue using Python 3 with Ansible and solved by forking the dopy project and installing dopy in my ansible script with:

`name: git+https://github.com/eodgooch/dopy@0.4.0#egg=dopy`.

If you are still getting errors be sure to change the `version` to `0.4.0` and remove any lingering dopy packages from your Python site-packages directory.

Also you could `pip3 install git+https://github.com/eodgooch/dopy@0.4.0#egg=dopy` instead of in your Ansible Task.

Comment: `pip uninstall dopy` and `pip3 install git+https://github.com/eodgooch/dopy@0.4.0#egg=dopy` worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Replace basestring with str. In 2.x basestring is there. but in 3.x the basestring has been replaced with "str".

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be due to python version. In 2.x, basestring is there but in 3.x it has been replaced with "str".

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to install `future` via `pip install future` and import `from past.builtins import basestring`.

```
from past.builtins import basestring
```

Personally, I'm not crazy about this solution because:

1. It requires installing another dependency.
2. There are likely other backward compatibility issues mixing Python 3 and 2 code.
3. It will only work in your code - you don't want to modify Ansible source code.

I offer it only because it's something I've used in the past to make my own code work in both Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

replace basestring with (str, bytes) and it should work perfectly

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).